# Javascript - Get query string from a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the query string from a string (not the current URL).

For example, I have a URL 'www.google.com/?query=string', I'd like to be able to run a function on it and get '?query=string' back from it. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to parse the query string also? Eg to get an object with `obj.query == 'string'` back?

Comment: Hi, No i'm just after the full query string, it's for an SEO reporting tool I'm working on. I think Alsciende's answer is what I am after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can use a quick regexp that gets you the part you need:

```
myString.match(/(\?.*)/)[1]
```

Example:

```
'www.google.com/?query=string'.match(/(\?.*)/)[1] // evaluates to '?query=string'
```

Answer (score 2):

Window.location.search will evaluate to this.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp

Answer (score 1):

There's [a jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) for that.

Comment: He said "not the current URL".

Comment: From what I've read in the documentation, you don't *have* to use the current URL. Maybe I read it wrong, or it's unclear, but this is what it says: "You can create a new query object based on a provided url through the load method," which sounds to me like you can pass in whatever string you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, use this plugin: http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/
This one lets you operate on the document's url, or any URL string

Then you can do:

```
$.url.setUrl("www.google.com/?query=string").attr("query") // returns 'query=string'
```

Or also get a specific parameter:

```
$.url.setUrl("www.google.com/?query=string").param("query") // returns 'string'
```

But if you really just need the whole query string, a quick regex like Alsciende suggested is the way to go.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, It was indeed just the whole query string I wanted, but I'm sure I'll need this plugin at some point, so thank you.